# Django SECRET KEY environmental variable not working in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my settings.py I have `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SETTINGS_SECRET_KEY')`

In my Elastic Beanstalk environmental variables I have:

```
SETTINGS_SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key'
```

If I don't set up an alternative, i.e.,

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SETTINGS_SECRET_KEY', 'abcde')
```

then my app doesn't run and I get an error saying that the SECRET_KEY cannot be empty.

It works in localhost with my SETTINGS_SECRET_KEY in .bashrc

Comment: Can you describe your Elastic Beanstalk setup more? I suspect you're not populating the environment correctly - are you using the Docker environment perhaps and accidentally setting the environment of the host and not the container?

Comment: @KristianGlass I am not using Docker, just a straight ebs deployment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']

Then configure the value via EBS Console (Application => Configuration => Software => Environment Properties) wherein key is DJANGO_SECRET_KEY and value is 'some_value_here' (include quotes, since Python settings will need to treat the value as a string).

Alternatively, use: eb setenv DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='some_value_here'