# Django secret key on elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any reason why this isn't working anymore? I'm getting key must not be empty even though I have env variable set in EB console.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372082/django-secret-key-environmental-variable-not-working-in-elastic-beanstalk
```

PS: This command on ssh returns None, what am I missing?

```
print(os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'))
```

None

Comment: First of all you didn't add the fallback and secondly this probably means that the variable isn't set. This would be a configuration error, not a django problem or even a Python problem.

Comment: Sorry! I started a week ago with Django! What do I add?

Answer (score 0):

> ssh returns None, what am I missing

If you just ssh to the EB, the EB env variables will not be source by default. You have to **explicitly source** them.

You can try the following to source them as root:

```
 export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```